# Too Many Redirects Error in Wordpress after deactivating plugins

Tags: php, wordpress

So.. I deactivated a whole page of plugins in one go with a mass action, and my site crashed. The home page has no theme, and the admin / login pages redirect too many times and don't respond.

Included in the plugins I deactivated were wordfence and a few other security plugins. I'm worried that by deactivating the entire page I might have knocked out some sort of dependancy. Any thoughts would be very appreciated.

.htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

WP_DEBUG notes:

```
[05-Jan-2018 05:58:36 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/mp-toolkit/widgets-attr/index.php
```

which is

```
 $widget_obj       = $wp_registered_widgets[ $widget_id ];
```

Comment: can you post your htaccess code?

Comment: Thanks - Added... looks pretty standard though.

Comment: can you able to login admin?

Comment: nope. I seem to have resolved the redirect, but now the site is basically just running in plaintext and php is unresponsive.

Comment: set true the `define('WP_DEBUG', false);` and check the error

Comment: Added the debug log ^

Comment: I will check this tomorrow. I'm on the way to home